# Ancient Isis Origin

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt

I am writing an essay on how ancient Isis was originated in Egypt.
I have 2 out of 3 points. 
Her temple in egypt and the ancient texts from egypt. I need 1 more point. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What point are you looking for? Are you looking for another resource or are you looking for how she was worshiped, who worshiped her, what was she the god of?

Comment: My essay is based on trying to 'prove' that ancient Isis was an Egyptian cult. So how she was worshipped etc is irrelevant. Her temple in Egypt and her name being reffered to in the pyramid texts in egypt both suggest that she and the cult originated in Egypt. I need one for point to suggest that Isis and/or the cult originated in Egypt. Thanks

Comment: Did any other cultures worship her in that form?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider what exactly you want to prove. Two options here:

- Isis worship was first established in an area that was Egyptian at the time, and not imported from surrounding areas. This will be almost impossible to prove or disprove, considering the lack of documentation on the surrounding cultures.
- Isis worship was present in Egypt before the Isis cult became popular in the Graeco-Roman world. This is relatively easy.

For your third point, consider how the Isis myth is integrated into the Egyptian [pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_deities). This is not conclusive, of course.

Comment: I want to prove the Isis worship was present in Egypt before anywhere else. I don't really understand what you mean about the myth being integrated?

Comment: @ToniGercovitch, you cannot prove that because you would have to prove a negative -- that there was **no** temple in some shack outside Egypt before the Egyptians built theirs. How can that be? Regarding integration, take a look at myths which contain Isis and other gods. Do they appear as if Isis has been inserted later? Or is Isis an integral part of the myth?

Answer (score 1):

The similarities with Maria in Christianity. Both had a Son from a spiritual father (The God Osiris was revived to impregnate Isis in bird guise while Maria was impregnated by a bird being representatieve for a god.) Isis hides her child in Egypt. So does Maria. Both to avoid murder. Both overcome Seth/Satan. Isis revives Osiris (Al-Aser-us) while Jesus revives Lazarus (what is in a name?). Joseph/Djoser show resemblances in ideographic reading of the mouth hieroglyph R>P by Semites resulting in a ‘Djoseph’ (Joseph) figure instead of a Djoser figure. This is all speculation, what could possibly proof all this? Osiris is the judge. Anyone who wants to go to tge afterlife has to pass by him. This is similar to Jesus’s teachings about reaching the father. The historical Jesus may well have been crucified but after his death his birth and life were adorned by Ancient Egyptian canon. And last but not least the pharaoh tombs in the pyramids are empty, just as Jesus’s grave. A possible read: Jesus, last of the pharaohs.

In the comments section you wrote;
“I want to prove the Isis worship was present in Egypt before anywhere else.” Isis is the Greek name for the Egyptian Auset so Isis as a name originates from Egyptian Greeks. Auset may well have been imported with Osires (Aser) from the Levant as Ashera/Astarte/Ishtar. What is certain is that Isis worship in Europe is based on The Egyptian Auset, but Egypt was not the start of that journey.